# Can't use Vuetify breakpoint in a computed global mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, responsive-design, vuetify.js

I often need to use `this.$vuetify.breakpoints` so I make a global mix-in out of it:

```js
/*
@/main.js
*/

// Declare the mixin
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    isOnPC () {
      console.log(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp)  // This logs correctly
      return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp
    }
  }
})

// Mount Vue
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

And then in the component I was hoping I could just do this:

```html
<!--
  @/views/View.vue
-->

<template>
  <div>
    <!-- Wrong component got rendered -->
    <!-- `isOnPC` has wrong value when inspected with Vue devtools -->
    <WideComponent v-if="isOnPC" />
    <NarrowComponent v-else />
  </div>
</template>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it and it seems to be working fine for me.. maybe try add a `!` on your "isOnPC" in your v-if like: `v-if="!isOnPC"`

This is how I tested it and it renders correctly for me:

```
//test.vue
  <div>
      <v-btn
        block
        color="red"
        v-if="isOnPC"
      > Hi </v-btn>
      <v-btn
        color="yellow"
        v-else
      > Bye </v-btn>
    </div>

//main.js
// Declare the mixin
Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    isOnPC() {
      console.log(this.$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndUp) // This logs correctly
      return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp
    }
  }
})
```